# Entity Framework raw SQL query and relation model

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a question about using T-SQL queries as model entity and mapping part of result as related entities.

I have this model class for example:

```
public class Device
{
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }

    public PlatformId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public PlatformName { get; set; }        
}
```

And I using the SQL query method from Entity Framework (client wants raw SQL and can't use normal data model mapping). SQL call looks like (where is is the main model):

```
public List<TResultModel> ExecuteSqlQuery<TResultModel>(string query)
{
    try
    {
        return this.DbConnection.Database.SqlQuery<TResultModel>(query).ToList<TResultModel>();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Sql query is fairly simple it gets list of devices and joins platforms, and one device can be found on couple of platforms so simple join:

```
select * 
from devices
join platforms on devices.platform_id = platforms.id order by platforms.name
```

If I use this SQL query, I am getting lots of duplicated devices.

Duplicated I mean a list of duplicated devices name with different platforms name for example:

```
Device | Platform

Dev A  |  Pl A
Dev A  |  PL B
Dev B  |  PL A
Dev B  |  PL B
```

And their id and name so I have to filter manually all those values (well by linq).

So I wonder if there is any way to map a model to such a SQL query so result can bind itself to model that could look like:

```
public class Device
{
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }

    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public List<Platform> Platforms { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: You could do that with a group by, but since you're doing a custom query string it will be tough to know what it needs to map to and if your mostly writing your own sql then EF might not be the best solution for you as it's much better suited to creating SQL for you from Linq queries.

Comment: What does your query look like?  If the issue is you're getting duplicates seems like that is an issue with the SQL query being passed in.